# How can I write a template/concept to check if a type meets the named requirement DefaultInsertable

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++-concepts

While implementing my own `forward_list` class template, I saw that some of the methods such as `resize()` require the type be *DefaultInsertable*.  According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable), *DefaultInsertable*

> Specifies that an instance of the type can be default-constructed
> in-place by a given allocator.

I understand what *DefaultConstructable* means and I can enforce that my type T meets this requirement either by using the `default_initializable` concept or with the following template:

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<(T(),T{},true),int*>>
```

where T is any type

But how could I verify that a type can be default-constructed *in place by a given allocator*?

Comment: for DefaultConstructable you can use `std::is_default_constructible<T>`